# Thread wait on Seda

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel, performance-testing, jbossfuse

We have been doing some SVP testing and have hit issues. We use JBoss Fuse 6.0 and camel. On close observation in monitoring software it seems we have a lot of wait on `org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer.process` . This is the case for several stalled transactions and poor times. We do use seda in our camel routes.

Any ideas what would be causing this. Would increasing concurrentconsumers solve this issue. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using transactions, as transactions requires synchronous routing to ensure transactional behavior, and therefore SEDA reacts accordingly.

Comment: No we dont use trasactions.

Comment: Its hard to say what will be the cause. Could you perhaps focus on one the routes that is causing this problem and post some code? For example if a seda route is talking to a database and there is some blocking happening on the DB due to page locks, row locks then you will have this problem and it wont be camel related. So focus on one of the poor performing areas and post it here so we can have a look.